# How to scroll extJS grid on top from somewhere in middle or end without using focus

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button , textfield and grid with huge amount of data. What i am doing is i am typing some number and on click of button i want my grid to select and show in view taht pericular record.

Example if i select 1200 then it will go to 1200th record and show in view from scrolling.

For this I am doing

`grid.getView().scrollIntoView(value)`

This is working fine but for large data it is failing. So What i am doing here is

grid.getView().scrollDelta('Y',value*10,true);

This also working fine. But my problem is whenever i enter new value I want scroll to be start from top. I am trying to use this code `grid.getView().focusRow( record );` and thing are working fine, but my focus getting changed.

I don't want my focus to be changed. Is there any other way I can start from the top.

Here is my code.

```
click : function(){
    var view = this.getView();
    var grid = view.down('myGrid');
    var value = view.down('field').getValue();
    //grid.getView().scrollIntoView(value);
    grid.getView().focusRow( record ); // Trying to put on top but not by this way
    grid.getView().scrollDelta('Y',value*10,true);
}
```

What is happening is suppose my value is 100, and if i enter new number then it is further scrolling down. (If I put 50 value it is scrolling to 150. I want to scroll 50 so i want to go on top first and then scroll again with having focus. )